# Mysql query Match and OR WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

hi if have this query:

```
 SELECT *,
      MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('book library' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS resources_score 
      FROM books  HAVING resources_score > 0 
      ORDER BY resources_score DESC, id DESC ;
```

is it possible to add a `OR WHERE title LIKE ;`

Also since my query is returnig resource_score as `1` or `0` , is it possible to have a more  query/search/results accuracy?

In the end, one tip dubt, query match accuracy depends on number of records?

thanks to who will help me

Comment: ehmm sorry for my english i mean accuracy!

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Realized that sounded less funny, more d**kish.

Comment: well ... i really don't know how to implement the OR, cause the WHERE without OR is ok but the only OR WHERE sounds bad, really don't know actually

Answer (score 1):

When all else fails, you can combine SQL functions using arithmetic.

```
 SELECT *,
 (title LIKE '%pattern%') + (MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('book library' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
   AS resources_score 
 FROM books HAVING resources_score > 0 
 ORDER BY resources_score DESC, id DESC ;
```

This will add 1 to the score returned by MATCH() when the title contains 'pattern'.